# Save encoded data to another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro code here in which saves the encoded data to another sheet within the same workbook. But I want to make some modification in this macro, I want the encoded data saves to another workbook, here is my code:

```
Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()
Dim i, lastrow As Long
If ActiveSheet.Range("d6") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("g6") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("c9") = "" Then
MsgBox "Please complete all fields!"
Exit Sub
End If

lastrow = Sheets("database").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
i = 9
Do While Cells(i, 3) <> "" And i < 29
Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 2) = ActiveSheet.Range("g6") ' Date
Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 3) = ActiveSheet.Range("d6") ' Ref
Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 4) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) ' Code
Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 5) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) ' Description
Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 6) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5) ' U/M
Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 7) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6) ' Qty
Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 8) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7) ' Price
Sheets("Database").Cells(lastrow, 9) = "IN" ' Transaction
i = i + 1
lastrow = lastrow + 1
Loop
MsgBox "Saved Succesfully!"
ThisWorkbook.Save
Call RoundedRectangle2_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, code would be like this..

```
Sub RoundedRectangle1_Click()
Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long, n As Long
Dim vResult()
Dim myWs As Worksheet

Set myWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Database")

If ActiveSheet.Range("d6") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("g6") = "" Or ActiveSheet.Range("c9") = "" Then
MsgBox "Please complete all fields!"
Exit Sub
End If

'lastrow = Sheets("database").Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
i = 9
Do While Cells(i, 3) <> "" And i < 29
    n = n + 1
    ReDim Preserve vResult(1 To 8, 1 To n)
    vResult(1, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("g6") ' Date
    vResult(2, n) = ActiveSheet.Range("d6") ' Ref
    vResult(3, n) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 3) ' Code
    vResult(4, n) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 4) ' Description
    vResult(5, n) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5) ' U/M
    vResult(6, n) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6) ' Qty
    vResult(7, n) = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7) ' Price
    vResult(8, n) = "IN" ' Transaction
    i = i + 1

Loop

Dim wb As Workbook
'chage workbook name as  your workbook.name
Set wb = Workbooks("another.xlsx")
With wb.Sheets("Database")
    .Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(n, 8) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vResult)
End With
myWs.Range("b" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(n, 8) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vResult)

MsgBox "Saved Succesfully!"
ThisWorkbook.Save
Call RoundedRectangle2_Click
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it, and has no errors, but there's no data appearing on the other workbook

Comment: match your the other workbook.name and  sheet name in code.

Comment: I got the portion where I will change the workbook name, but where will I change the sheet name?

Comment: With wb.Sheets("your sheet name")

Comment: silly me, haha, I got it, and it worked perfectly, thanks for that. Hmm may I ask another one? what if I want the data to be save in the same workbook and in the other workbook. When I encode a data and run the macro, the data will be saved in the "database" sheet in the same workbook and in the "database" sheet on the other workbook at the same time?

Comment: Ysmael Cailon,I modified my code , the data be inable to save in the same workbook and in the other workbook at the same time.